# In Golang, can I assign slice values as return values?

Tags: go, return-value, variable-assignment, slice, idioms

I am attempting to develop a passthrough function for error checking where certain arguments are evaluated, and the rest are returned.  But I would like these to be returned as multiple return values rather than a slice.  Is there any way to do this in Go?  Here's an example:

```
func Check(args ...interface{}) ...interface{} {
    last := len(args) - 1
    err := args[last]

    // Check for an error in the last argument
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Return any args returned by the function we're checking
    return ...args[:last]
}
```

I know this isn't quite formated right in the function declaration.  This is just for the sake of argument.  I would ideally like to be able to return a variable number of values, which could then be received on the other side via assignment.  This would allow for simple inline error checking when I want to use the standard err/panic idiom.

I know that I could return the slice instead and then assign it's parts to individual variables, or I could create multiple such functions (e.g. Check0, Check1, Check2, etc.), each having a distinct number or return values, but neither of these solutions is very elegant.  Any ideas on how to make something like this work gracefully?  Or is it just not possible at this stage of Go?

On a related note, does anyone know if there are any plans to make slices unpackable into variables, something like the following?

```
one, two, three := []string{"one", "two", "three"}
```

Comment: First, stick with the `if err != nil { return err }` thing for long enough for it to quit being annoying. You can get used to it, I swear. If you have a long series of I/O operations, and the whole program or HTTP request or whatever must crash and show an error whenever any of them fail for any reason, forevermore, I think a `panic()`ing wrapper is OK (not sure most Gophers agree), but even then don't use `interface{}`; one design could be a package named `must` exporting `Read`, `Write`, etc. functions, as in `n := must.Read(reader, p)`, the `must` name borrowed from `regexp.MustCompile`.

Comment: I don't think slices will ever be unpackable in Go, and here's why: unpacking would have fail at run time if the slice wasn't the expected length (as it does when I make mistakes in Python), which makes it pretty different in spirit from statically-checked multiple assignments that exist now. Doubt the Go folks would ever change assignment from a safe to a potentially-panicking operation.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I should just stick with the standard err form.  Dunno.  On the second question, seems like it could work even if lengths were different. If fewer variables than the slice members, throw out the remaining values.  If more variables than slice members, set extra variables to nil.  Then error checks could be done as needed on each variable. Seems like that sort of handling is still generally in the Go spirit.  Would be a very convenient construct to have.

Comment: At this point we're just talking hypotheticals for fun, but note that behavior lacks the static types-and-count check you get now, and the run-time exception that catches some of my Python mistakes. Perl does do what you're proposing, but (getting back to the specific question) no indications that Go will.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, I don't think that's even planned, which is a good thing IMO.

Your option is doing something like this (this is ugly, and shouldn't be used):

```
func Check(args ...interface{}) []interface{} {
    if err := args[len(args)-1]; err != nil {
        //do suff with err
    }
    args = args[:len(args)-1]
    return args
}

func Check2i(args ...interface{}) (int, int) {
    return args[0].(int), args[1].(int)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Check(10, 20, 30, nil)...)
    a, b := Check2i(Check(10, 20, nil)...)
    _, _ = a, b
}
```